# Same artifact uses different versions of same dependency

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am using maven enforcer plugin but I found this strange case of dependency convergence:

```
Dependency convergence error for commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1 paths to dependency are:
+-ProjectA:B:0.1
  +-commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6
    +-commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2
      +-commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
and
+-ProjectA:B:0.1
  +-commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6
    +-commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
```

And this is the dependency declaration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

you can see that the same artifact uses different versions of the same dependency.
How can this happen? also the only way to suppress the warning is by including the latest version of that dependency as a direct dependency in my pom.

Am I missing something?

Comment: If possible, could you please post the pom.xml file ?

Comment: @Sambit I've added the dependency declaration, unfortunately the pom can't be fully posted outside of the company.

Comment: Are you using multi module maven project ?

Comment: Yes, this dependency is declared in a child module, and the parent module -as a result of refactoring- has only 1 module, that is this child

Comment: I think of one solution ie. move the commons-validator dependency to the parent pom.xml and comment out the the dependency for commons-collections:3.2.1.

Comment: Simply declare within a dependencyManagement block with the dependency commons-collections and the version you would like to have..

Comment: @khmarbaise and Sambit thanks a lot, I was confused how can convergence happen within another project, not all projects use the enforcer plugin :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the dependency tree you see that `commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6` directly depends on `commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2`, but has also a transitive dependency on `commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1`. Nothing unusual about that.

To resolve this you need to choose a version. Just follow the advice of khmarbaise and add an entry to the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your POM.

Comment: I didn't know this wasn't unusual :) It's frustrating to have to fix/suppress dependency convergence for other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Above all that same artifact doesn`t use different versions of the same dependency.

```
+-ProjectA:B:0.1
  +-commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6
    +-commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.2
      +-commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1
and
+-ProjectA:B:0.1
  +-commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6
    +-commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
```

Dependency `commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6` uses `commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2` directly and `commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1` transitively (dependency of an other dependency). Maven`s dependency mediation will resolve this conflict based on neares-newest principle.
Take a look at these: 
[1] [Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)
[2] [Dependency Mediation and Conflict Resolution](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution)

The maven-enforcer-plugin`s dependencyConvergence rule works fine.
As the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) says:

> This rule requires that dependency version numbers converge. If a
>   project has two dependencies, A and B, both depending on the same
>   artifact, C, this rule will fail the build if A depends on a different
>   version of C then the version of C depended on by B.

Because commons-validator (A) and commons-beanutils (B) depending on commons-collections (C) and those dependecies has different versions this behaviour is totally reasonable.

### You decide what do you want to exactly do.

#### Keep using dependencyConvergence rule and resolve this error

In this case just define `commons-collections`, `commons-logging` and `commons-validator` in `<dependencyManagement>` section and put those dependencies as managed dependences in your project.

```xml
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I think it needs a lot of overwork and after a while your project model will be unmaintenable. On the other hand `Dependency Mediation` rule resolves this problem.

#### Use other rule e.g. requireUpperBoundDeps

This rule is designed to investigagte if a resolved dependency during a build is lower than all transitive dependeny declarations. E.g. it will fail if your project depending on `commons-collections:3.0` but `commons-validator` requires newer version `commons-collections:3.2.2`

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

#### Forget enforcer and trust in Dependency Mediation

Almost all cases this is the right decision because `Dependency Mediation` is works fine.

Comment: I cannot support the first advice. Please always use `<dependencyManagement>` to manage dependency versions, not exclusions or unnecessary direct dependencies.

Comment: I agree with you it should be in `<dependencyManagement>` but that way is correct. I mean those transitive dependencies sould be excluded somewhere otherwise `dependencyConvergence` rule will fail. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: You don't need any exclusions here. I have done that many times before. `<dependencyManagement>` is enough to ensure dependencyConvergence.